# SWF doesn't render in IE9 (but does in Chrome/FF)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, flash, swfobject

The following code is **NOT** rendering a swf from a remote webpage hosted from IIS7 in IE9 but does so in Chrome and FF.

What am I missing?

File: http://srv.ab.com/page/swftestpage.htm

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        (function () {

            var object = document.createElement('object');
            object.setAttribute('width', '300');
            object.setAttribute('height', '250');
            object.setAttribute('classid', 'clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000');

            var param1 = document.createElement('param');
            param1.setAttribute('name', 'movie');
            param1.setAttribute('value', 'http://srv.ab.com/test.swf');

            var embed = document.createElement('embed');
            embed.setAttribute('src', 'http://srv.ab.com/test.swf');
            embed.setAttribute('width', '300');
            embed.setAttribute('height', '250');

            var param2 = document.createElement('param');
            param2.setAttribute('name', 'wmode');
            param2.setAttribute('value', 'transparent');

            object.appendChild(param1);
            object.appendChild(embed);
            object.appendChild(param2);

            var container = document.getElementById('myDivID');
            while (container.firstChild) { container.removeChild(container.firstChild); }
            container.appendChild(object);
        })();

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct attribute on the `<object>` tag is `classid`. You have `clsid`

Reference - http://www.alistapart.com/articles/flashembedcagematch/

I would seriously just use [SWFObject's dynamic publishing](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation#How_to_embed_Flash_Player_content_using_SWFObject_dynamic_publis) instead of re-inventing the wheel here

Comment: Thx for the reply. I updated the post as well as my code on the web page and tested it but it's still not rendering.

Comment: Hi Phil. Not sure I will be able to use the swfboject. I should have added this n the details but the reason being is that there are numerous clients call my api <script type="text/javascript" src="http//:srv.ab.com/api/getswf?divIdToReplace=Div1"</script> and i essentially replace a divid as specified in the query string with the contents from above in order to display the swf.  So, I have to use straight js instead of any libs or plugins.  Thoughts?